# Should questions about perpetual motion machines be preserved?

Tags: discussion, questions

We have two questions on this site about perpetual motion machines.

- [Solar energy without the sun: Super LED light on top of solar panels?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2658/1056)
- [Getting power from an innovative new mechanism](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6102/1056)

Both questions were heavily downvoted *(good for us!)* but neither question was closed, apparently because the connection to energy is sufficient to be considered on-topic. Still, this question deserves only one kind of answer:

> No, you cannot due to the second law of thermodynamics. No, you cannot get more energy out than you put in. No, you cannot invent a perpetual motion machine.

Do we want to preserve these questions, or should they be deleted from the site?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. My proposal:

- Vote to close.  This reduces the prominence, doesn't allow for new answers, but keeps the good responses which explain why perpetual motion machines don't work.
- Use a default/standard close reason. Right now we don't have one, but perhaps something like: "This question is about perpetual motion machines, which are off-topic for this site."
- Mark all future questions on this topic as duplicates of these two.

Comment: If preservation is what we want then a historic lock might be more appropriate here than closure - it stops voting, comments and answers - basically making the question 'read only' to regular users (mods can still do some things including removing the lock). A closed question can still be voted on, commented, reopened or deleted by regular users. Historic locks can only be applied by mods though.

Comment: Personally I'm indifferent whether we close or lock such a question, either is fine with me (I closed one of them already, the other is still open). With 2 questions in 7 years I do think there is no need to make any special arrangements for this, like adding a default close reason, unless we start seeing much more questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea might be to create a generically written 'catch all' community wiki question and answer, which describes the general failings of a perpetual motion machine. This could then be used as a duplicate target for the current (and any future) perpetual motion questions. Something like the following:

> ### Is it possible to generate unlimited energy?
>
> I have an idea to generate potentially unlimited energy.
>
> Is this possible? Will my contraption work?
>
> ---
>
> [energy](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy)[electricity-generation](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity-generation)

Answer:

> What you are describing is a **perpetual motion machine**, and **no,** it won't work.
>
> Energy can not be created nor destroyed; it can only be [transformed or transferred from one form to another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy). This means, you cannot get more energy out than you put in....

What do you think?

Comment: I wasn't sure at first, but now I am warming up to this idea.

Comment: I like it. Given the LED question (which to my surprise has 40K+ views!!) we probably also want to cover "recycling energy for ever" in such a question.

Comment: @THelper yeah good idea. I didn't really expand on the answer too much in my example above but ultimately it can be as descriptive as we'd like - probably with multiple sections properly 'debunking' these sorts of "free energy!" myths